# Scrolling a Tilemap in Sprite-Kit (JSTileMap glitch)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, jstilemap

Since JSTileMap extends SKNode, you can use the API to move and animate your tilemap like any other node. However, I keep getting this weird effect/glitch...

Code:

```
_tiledMap = [JSTileMap mapNamed:@"Cloud.tmx"];
if (_tiledMap) {
    [self addChild:_tiledMap];
}
_tiledMap.position = CGPointMake(800, 0);

SKAction *scrollLeft = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(600, 0) duration:4];
SKAction *scrollRight = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(700, 0) duration:4];
SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[scrollLeft, scrollRight]];
SKAction *repeat   = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];
[_tiledMap runAction:repeat];
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, whenever the JSTileMap changes direction, depending if its left or right, the image gets cropped or something, I can't explain it. This doesn't happen if the node itself is a SKSpriteNode. I added numbers to the background image for visual reference.

---

EDIT

Further tests reveal that moving the JSTileMap's position manually (_tiledMap.position.x = x+1) in the update loop, has the same effect. It crops the image/tile when it animates left, and returns to normal when it animates to the right.

Comment: Don't move the map but instead move the visible view over the map.

Comment: Have you tried adding the JSTileMap to an SKNode and moving the SKNode instead?

Comment: @Code Monkey, I have tried adding the JSTileMap as a child of an SKSpriteNode and moving that instead, same results. Sangony, Please clarify.

Comment: If you place the JSTileMap with _tiledMap.position = CGPoint(x,y) to the region where you have the issue (without using SKAction), does it render correctly?

Comment: I ran some tests. It appears the same thing happens if I manually change the _tilemap.position (i.g. _tiledMap.position = CGPointMake(_tiledMap.position.x+1.0, 0  on every update loop). The region, or position where the glitch happens is arbitrary, it happens anywhere on the screen where the tile is being animated. Note, however, that it only crops the image when animating to the left. When I animate the image to the right, it goes back to normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I was using an old/unmaintained version of JSTileMap. Slycrel's version of JSTileMap addresses this issue.

https://github.com/slycrel/JSTileMap

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around. Apparently the problem is that the first tileset column itself is being cropped for some reason (if anyone figures this out please let me know). So the solution is to create a tilemap that is 2 tile units wider than what your original tilemap dimension is. For example, if your tiles are set to 32x32 (tilemap of 1024x768), you should generate a tilemap of 1088x768 instead and start drawing after the first column.

See image below.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is JSTileMap and can you implement something similar using built-in sprite kit features?

Comment: @Code Monkey, JSTileMap allows you to use tile map editors (I'm using Tiled) in sprite-kit. If you're not familiar with tile map editors, they allow you to create map layouts for your game - so instead of using a huge image for your background, it breaks up the entire map into tiles (i.g. 32x32 tiles). Sprite-kit (JSTileMap) then loads only the visible tiles from the tilemap, making memory management a lot better. I am not aware of anything similar native to sprite-kit, please explain.

Comment: @JonnyRamos can you submit an example project as an issue on github?  I'd like to take a further look and see if I can fix the problem.  (https://github.com/slycrel/JSTileMap/issues)

Comment: Downvote because the tip seems to be obsolete after the update (see OP's other answer)

Comment: im using xcode tilemap editor in spritekit 3 and for no reason when my character is moving left it's animation kinda glitchy. I tried to empty one line of tiles from top, down, left, right as like in this answer and glitch is gone. +1